# Sharepoint 2010 grab SIP address from AD?

Tags: user-profile, administration, user-profile-service, user-accounts, user-profile-property

I would like to have the 'SIP Address' (eg. sip:myname.companyname.com) field automatically filled in so we can use Portal's 'presence' functionality - as far as I can see we have no dedicated LDAP attribute for this information.

I would be very grateful of some advice on how to get this data into SharePoint 2010?

Comment: Where were you wanting to have this field "automatically filled"?  In the user profile?  Are you syncing your user profile data from AD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hidden list called SiteUserInfoList on each web, use it to get sip.

```
private string GetSipAddress(SPUser user, SPWeb web)
{
    web = web ?? SPContext.Current.Web;
    var userItem = web.SiteUserInfoList.GetItemById(user.ID);
    string sip = string.Empty;
    if (userItem != null) 
    {
        var sipAddress = userItem["SipAddress"];
        if (sipAddress != null)
        {
            sip = sipAddress.ToString().Replace("sip:", "");
        }
    }
    return sip;
}
```

There is a [post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/elad/archive/2010/12/14/getting-sip-address-of-a-user-in-sharepoint.aspx) about it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using AD and the MS SIP infrastructure (OCS/Lync), you should have an attribute in AD called "msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress".  You should be able to map this to any user profile attribute you like during synchronization.  I'm a little surprised this wouldn't already be getting mapped to the SIP Address attribute, but I guess that depends on what you have setup.