# Presence indicators

Tags: user-profile, presence-indication

I want to add presence indicators to my custom webpart. I have found a [blog post about it](http://www.dotnetspark.com/links/30386-communicator-presence-bubble---can-i-change.aspx).

```
string.Format("<li><a class=\"ms-imnlink\" href=\"javascript:;\"><img width=\"12\" height=\"12\" id=\"IMID12\" onload=\"IMNRC(&#39;", Contact.Email, "&#39;)\" alt=\"My SID\" src=\"/_layouts/images/imnoff.png\" border=\"0\" showofflinepawn=\"1\"/ sip=\" \"></a>&#160;{0}</li>"
```

I know even [how to get sip address](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16765/sharepoint-2010-grab-sip-address-from-ad).

But isn't there an easier way to show the presence indicator? Doesn't Sharepoint API any webcontrols for that?

Comment: The most important thing is to provide a unique client id. perhaps with `int counter` or like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're rolling your own web part, then yes you have to add them in.  If you start from a list view, and the web application has the presence information enabled, then you can convert the list view web part to a dataview web part and the presense information should be included in the markup.